# OAuth 2.0 Authorization : "authorization code" does not get after updating sandbox to spring 20 release

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0, salesforce, webbrowser-control

I am using c#.net code to do OAuth2.0 authorization with salesforce(Please find below url example).

```
  - For authorization: SANDBOX URL/services/oauth2/authorize
  - For token requests: SANDBOX URL/services/oauth2/token
```

- OAuth 2.0 authorization of Sandbox was working very well before updating to spring 20 release.
- After updating sandbox to spring 20 release i found that "authorization code" code does not getting by using url  SANDBOX URL/services/oauth2/authorize and  hence i can not use token request to get token.

For example:
Let's say I have the salesforce Sandbox Endpoint URL like : https://test.salesforce.com/

Authorization url : https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
Token requests url : https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Navigation url : https://test.salesforce.com//services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=your_client_id&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success&prompt=login";

Now, I am using WPF webbrowser to navigate above url to get access token, then after entering correct credentials also I do not get the correct redirect URL from salesforce sanbox. Due to which I do not get access token.

Comment: Please add more details when you add a question. You described the problem but we need to see what you have tried, what has worked and what hasn't. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Comment: Mine works fine... so, since we cant see your code, there is not much else we can say

Comment: @Edney Holder, Please check now I have updated the description